# typeahead.js in Django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, typeahead.js

There are examples on https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
I need to make a similar thing in my django app for searching hashtags.
But I tried and it doesn't work. 
There is a similar question and got ansewred on stackoverflow, but i dont get it out how to do it. 
[Using typeahead.js in Django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465052/using-typeahead-js-in-django-project)

views.py

```
class SearchTag(View):
""" Search tags with autocomplete (live search) """

def get(self, request):
    form = SearchTagForm()
    context = {'searchtag' : form}
    return render(request, 'search_tags.html', context)

def post(self,request):
    q = request.POST['q']
    form = SearchTagForm()
    tags = HashTag.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
    context = {'tags' : tags, 'searchtag' : form}
    return render(request, 'search_tags.html', context)

class TagJson(View):
    """Search a hashTag with auto complete feature"""
    def get(self, request):
        q = request.GET.get('q','')
        taglist = []
        tags = HashTag.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        for tag in tags:
            new = {'q' : tag.name}
            taglist.append(new)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(taglist), content_type="application/json")
```

models.py

```
class HashTag(models.Model):
''' HashTag model '''
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
post = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class SearchTagForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'size' : 30,
        'class' : 'form-control search-tag-query typeahead',
        'id' : 'typeahead'
    }))
```

and in html it looks like this

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="30" class="form-control search-tag-query typeahead" id="typeahead" required="">
```

i got the typahead.bundle.js connected and also a file search_tag.js
search_tag.js

```
var hashTags = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '/hashtag.json?q=%QUERY',
  remote: {
    url: '/hashtag.json?q=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'hashTags',
  display: 'value',
  source: hashTags
});
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^hashtag.json$', TagJson.as_view(), name = 'tagjson')
```

If i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hashtag.json?q=h
I get [{"q": "#hashtag"}, {"q": "#hashtags"}]

and in my browser developer console I get this wen typing every key.

jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hashtag.json?q=h".

jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hashtag.json?q=ha".

Probably everything works.
But still the the typeahead is not working so i can see it like in the examples on this page https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
 And I dont get it what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for search_tag.js made everything work according to all the other code i had on top. 
Here is a video i wrote, how to connect typeahead.js but it is in my native Russian language: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwOHnWSCYFc
If you have the same problems be sure to check the difference in my search_tag.js on top and this one, you will see what you have to change.

```
var hashTags = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('q'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '/hashtag.json?q=%QUERY',
  remote: {
    url: '/hashtag.json?q=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'hashTags',
  displayKey: 'q',
  source: hashTags.ttAdapter()
});
```