# Typeahead returning object count instead of selectable strings in Django

Tags: javascript, django, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to implement `typeahead.js` for my application. I followed through with some of the following examples [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465052/using-typeahead-js-in-django-project) and [Twitter typeahead official doc](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). I created a Django Rest API which works perfectly well, I have also been able to get the `typeahead` to pop up suggestions. After all these, I am faced with two difficulties that I have been unable to resolve on my own. The first is that instead of showing string results, the script is returning total object count [image: see screenshot], while the second problem is that the pop-up suggestion is not selectable.

Is there a way to solve these issues?

`main.js`

```
//live search
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchResults = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('lead'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: '../auth/api/data/',
        remote: {
            url: "/auth/api/data/",
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
        }
    });

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null,
        {
            name: 'leads-display',
            display: 'lead',
            source: searchResults,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                      '<div class="empty-message">',
                        'No user found',
                      '</div>'
                ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: function(data){
                    return '<div class="live-search-results">'
                    + '<strong>' + data + '</strong>'
                    + '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi , do `console.log(data)` inside your `suggestion: function(data){` see what it gives you .

Comment: @Swati Here is the error I am getting

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at getSuggestionNode (typeahead.bundle.js:1666)
    at Number.reverseArgs (typeahead.bundle.js:968)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.js:385)
    at Object.each (typeahead.bundle.js:966)
    at Dataset.getSuggestionsFragment [as _getSuggestionsFragment] (typeahead.bundle.js:1662)
    at Dataset.renderSuggestions [as _renderSuggestions] (typeahead.bundle.js:1628)
    at Dataset.append [as _append] (typeahead.bundle.js:1620)
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. The first thing I did was that I discarded my DRF API because I was faced with too many issues around it. So, instead of rest API, I created a `JSON` view in my `views.py` as seen below

```
    def get_leads(request):
        results = []
        lead = request.GET.get('lead')
        users = User.objects.filter(name__icontains=lead)
        data = [{'id': user.pk, 'name': user.name, 'avatar': user.avatar, 'email': user.email} for user in users]
        return JsonResponse(data, encoder=ExtendedEncoder, safe=False)
```

I also ensured that I serialised my FileField using `simplejson` because I want to show images in my search results.
`encoder.py`

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile

# custom JSON encoder for FieldFile
class ExtendedEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, FieldFile):
            return str(obj)
        return super(ExtendedEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Finally, in my `.js` file, I did the following

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var substringMatcher = function(strings) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var data, substringRegex;
        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];
        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substringRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strings, function(i, string) {
          if (substringRegex.test(string)) {
            matches.push(string);
          }
        });
        cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var leads = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/xxx/xxxx/?lead=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
        },
        {
        name: 'lead',
        limit: 15,
        display: 'name',
        source: leads,
        templates: {
             empty: [
                  '<div class="empty-message">',
                    'No user found',
                  '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function(data){
                console.log(data) //print result as a json object in console log
                var spanId = data.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
                return '<div class="live-search-results">'
                + '<span class="input-field-live-search-result"' + 'id="'+ spanId +'">'
                + '<img class="live-search-image"' + 'src="/media/' + data.avatar + '"' + 'alt="'
                + data.name + "'s avatar" + '"' + 'width="25px" height="25px" />' + data.name + ' - ' + data.email
                + '</span> </div>';
            },
        }
    });
  });
```

I hope this helps anyone that is faced or might face a similar issue.